# Parse string with tag that position might reverse sometimes

Tags: python, python-re

I'm trying to parse a string from log communicating with network which will be like

```
2019 Jun 30 15:40:17.561 NETWORK_MESSAGE
Direction = UE_TO_NETWORK
From: <1106994972>
To: <3626301680>
```

and here is my code:

```
import re
log = '2019 Jun 30 15:40:17.561 NETWORK_MESSAGE\r\nDirection = UE_TO_NETWORK\r\nFrom: <1106994972>\r\nTo: <3626301680>\r\n'
PATTERN = re.compile(
    '(?P<time>\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}.\d{3}).*'  # Time
    'Direction = (?P<Direction>\S+).*'     # Direction
    'From: <(?P<From>\S+)>.*'              # from
    'To: <(?P<To>\S+)>',                   # to
    re.DOTALL)
results = PATTERN.search(log)
print(results.group('From'))
```

However, I just found sometimes there will be reversed position between "From" and "To", just like the following.

```
2019 Jun 30 15:40:16.548 NETWORK_MESSAGE
Direction = NETWORK_TO_UE
To: <3626301680>
From: <1106994972>
```

Is it possible I can solve this with only one pattern?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution that uses `(From|To)` to match either `From` or `To` and then explicitly checks which of the two places matched `From`:

```
import re
log1 = '2019 Jun 30 15:40:17.561 NETWORK_MESSAGE\r\nDirection = UE_TO_NETWORK\r\nFrom: <1106994972>\r\nTo: <3626301680>\r\n'
log2 = '2019 Jun 30 15:40:17.561 NETWORK_MESSAGE\r\nDirection = UE_TO_NETWORK\r\nTo: <3626301680>\r\nFrom: <1106994972>\r\n'


PATTERN = re.compile(
    '(?P<time>\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}.\d{3}).*'  # Time
    'Direction = (?P<Direction>\S+).*'     # Direction
    '(?P<tag1>From|To): <(?P<val1>\S+)>.*' # from or to
    '(?P<tag2>From|To): <(?P<val2>\S+)>',  # from or to
    re.DOTALL)
for log in [log1, log2]:
    results = PATTERN.search(log)
    if results.group('tag1') == 'From':
        print(results.group('val1'))
    elif results.group('tag2') == 'From':
        print(results.group('val2'))
```

This matches your line but does not make sure there is exactly on `From` and one `To`.
I also considered this pattern

```
PATTERN = re.compile(
    '(?P<time>\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}.\d{3}).*'  # Time
    'Direction = (?P<Direction>\S+).*'     # Direction
    '(?P<FromTo>(?P<tag1>From|To): <(?P<val1>\S+)>.*){2}', # from or to
    re.DOTALL)
```

but this will only capture the *last* match in `From` and `To` (according to the [docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.MatchObject.group) "If a group is contained in a part of the pattern that matched multiple times, the last match is returned."). So if the two fields appear in the wrong order then you will not be able to get the value for `From`.

If things get more complicated you may have more readable code by using more than one pattern.

Answer (score 1):

```
log1 = "2019 Jun 30 15:40:17.561 NETWORK_MESSAGE\r\nDirection = UE_TO_NETWORK\r\nFrom: <1106994972>\r\nTo: <3626301680>\r\n"
log2 = "2019 Jun 30 15:40:16.548 NETWORK_MESSAGE\r\nDirection = NETWORK_TO_UE\r\nTo: <3626301680>\r\nFrom: <1106994972>\r\n"

PATTERN = re.compile(
    '(?P<time>\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}.\d{3}).*'  # Time
    'Direction = (?P<Direction>\S+).*'     # Direction
    '(From|To): <(?P<X>\S+)>.*'             
    '(To|From): <(?P<Y>\S+)>',                 
    re.DOTALL)

print(re.findall(PATTERN, log1))
print(re.findall(PATTERN, log2))
```